# React.JS - Passing data from one component to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sqlite, parameter-passing

Disclaimer: I am rather new to "React.JS".

I am trying to get a value from one component, so I can use it in my other component to display the appropriate content. Component 1 lists all shows from my database. Component 2 has the information about each specific show on a page of his own. I want to do this without hard-coding, as this would be described as not a good approach.

Here is the code:

**Component1.JSX**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SecondPage.css';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, ButtonDropdown } from 'reactstrap';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Showing from '../Showing/Showing.jsx';


class SecondPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showingsList: [],
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const self = this;
    axios.get('/api/loadShowings')
    .then(response => {
      var  showingsList  = response.data
   this.setState({ showingsList });

  }
    );

  }

  handleSubmit(){

  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div class="grid-container1">
      {
        this.state.showingsList.map((showing) => {
          return <div showing = {showing} key = {showing.id}>
            <div class="grid-item1 "><img width = "200px" height = "200px" src={showing.image}/>
            <h3>{showing.title}</h3>
            <h5>{showing.description}</h5>
            <Link to = "/Showing">
            <Button  className="btnShowings">MORE</Button>
            </Link>
        </div>







          </div>})
      }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default SecondPage;
```

**Component2.JSX**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Showing.css';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import {Button} from 'reactstrap';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Showing extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          showingsList: [], 
        };

      }

      componentDidMount(){
        const self = this;
        axios.get('/api/loadShowings')
        .then(response => {
          var  showingsList  = response.data
       this.setState({ showingsList });
       console.log(showingsList["0"].title)


      }
        );

      }

    render(){
        return(
<div>

      {
        this.state.showingsList.map((showing) => {
          return <div showing = {showing} key = {showing.id}>


          <Helmet>
          <style>{'body { background-color: gray; }'}</style>
          </Helmet>


            <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="item1">{showing.title}</div>
            <div class="item2"><img width = "200px" height = "200px" src={showing.image}/></div>
            <div class="item3">{showing.description}</div>  
            <div class="item4"> <a href = "/Booking">
                    <Button bsStyle="info" size = "lg">Make a booking</Button>
                    </a></div>

            </div>



          </div>})
      }

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Showing;
```

I tried a couple of things I've seen from various tutorials - using "this.props.state", but couldn't get it to work, as the example was made on the main JSX file (App.js). I also tried doing axios post and get, but it becomes so complicated. I am asking for an advice on what to use, so I don't have to create a lot of different pages for each case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you have two separate components? They have different purposes probably, right? So, you have a few options here. `Component1` can render `Component2`, so you can pass the `showingLists` state property to it. Or, you can lift your state up, in a parent component you fetch the shows, set your state and pass it to both components.

Comment: That's a great idea, but i will need a Component 3 in the future as well. Is it possible to have a sub-child if I do it this way?

Comment: Which "way exactly? Rule of thumb: If all those components will use/share the same state (`showingLists`), so just create a container component and do the fetch thing there. Then render your components in this container and pass the state to them. A few good links for you. [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Container/Presentational components (Dan Abramov)](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) And maybe [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Okay, will do that. Thank you very much!